# Is it impossible to dissect a parallelogram into an odd number of triangles of equal area? (Monsky's Theorem for parallelograms)

Tags: geometry

[Monsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky%27s_theorem) states that *it is not possible to dissect a square into an odd number of triangles of equal area*.

I read somewhere that Monsky's theorem is valid for parallelograms and not just squares. Can someone explain how?

Comment: To be clear: Are you referring to [Monsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky%27s_theorem) stating "It is not possible to dissect a square into an odd number of triangles of equal area"?

Comment: Yes. I am. Apologise for any ambiguity

Comment: At what point does the proof for squares fail for parallelograms?

Comment: A nice explanation of the (initial) Monsky theorem [here](https://simpletonsymposium.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/monskys-theorem-or-the-genius-of-bizarre-thinking/)

Comment: @JeanMarie It appears, after a quick perusal, that he only proves that there's no simplicial decomposition into an odd number of triangles, but Monsky's theorem is more general.  Maybe I overlooked something, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the parallelogram statement follows from the square statement.  Proof:  a parallelogram can be turned into a rectangle by a shear transformation, and then into a square by stretching it in one direction.  These transformations scale area by a constant, and they turn triangles into triangles.  So if you can dissect a parallelogram into an odd number of triangles of equal area, then shearing and stretching the entire picture will give a similar dissection of a square.

Answer (score 2):

Tilting a square to make a parallelogram is a linear transformation so it preserves lines and since it's invertible any decomposition of the parallelogram would give a decomposition of a square which would be impossible.